# Merge two arrays to common values only

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, merge

I looked at this very popular SO question:

[How to merge two arrays of JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top)

Where the OP has this:

```
   var array1 = ["Vijendra","Singh"];
   var array2 = ["Singh", "Shakya"];
```

Then he says, "I want the output to be:"

```
   var array3 = ["Vijendra","Singh","Shakya"];
```

**My question is "How do you just get Singh as a result?"**

```
   var array3 = ["Singh"];
```

In other words, how do you combine two arrays and only keep data that are common to both?  I've looked at merge, concat, intersect, and other options, but I can't seem to get this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter e.g. the first array `array1` from the elements which are also present in the second `array2` array.

```js
var array1 = ["Vijendra","Singh"],
    array2 = ["Singh", "Shakya"],
    res = array1.filter(v => array2.indexOf(v) > -1);
    
    console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you.  Apparently this question is a dupe, but I find "merge two arrays" to be much more intuitive than "array intersection" and I didn't find the other post.  Your approach works.

Comment: @SQLDBA My pleasure